# Put the top corner (not the center) of something in a point, in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

When we write something into "node{...}", for example:

```
    \draw (9,-7) node{
                       $\begin{split} 
                          A\le V \hspace{0.5cm} & \Longleftrightarrow \hspace{0.5cm}
                            \left\lbrace 
                           \begin{array}{ll}
                            a+a'\in A & \forall a,a'\in \\
                            \lambda a\in A & \forall \lambda \in F
                           \end{array}\right.  \\[0.75cm]  & 
                             \Longleftrightarrow \hspace{0.5cm} 
                           \lambda a+a'\in A\ \ \forall a,a'\in A, \lambda \in F
                      \end{split}$
                     }
```

latex put the **center** of the shape of the above formulas to the point (9,-7).
How can I put the left(or right) **top corner** of that to the point (9,-7)? Is there any code or even any way to do this work?(Of course without "testing over and over")

Comment: `node[anchor=north west]`?

Comment: @Rmano Thank you very very much. I wanted something like this for many days.

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that `above` is the same as `anchor=south` and `below left` is the same as `anchor=north east` and so on...  see https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add some option for node

```tex
node[above]
```